# MacOS complete search in huge text file and output results (find solution to TextPipe)

Tags: macos, search, vim, terminal

I have a text file ar. 50 GB size.
I used to process it through TextPipe but atm only mac is available and no TextPipe access.
Is it possible to initiate regex search in this file with good results saving to some other file per matching line?
I was thinking about vim editor but have no sufficient knowledge on where to search for.
Would appreciate any suggestions.

As an example let's assume that I have the code below in my initial.txt file and I want to save lines with "Lorem" in line processed.txt.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed strings use `fgrep`:

```
fgrep Lorem initial.txt > processed.txt
```

For regular expressions use `grep` and `egrep` (they have slightly different regexp syntax).

Comment: `fgrep` is just `grep -F`; `egrep` just `grep -E`.

Comment: Only if these are greps from GNU utilities. Other implementations could have different options. I don't know what greps are installed by default on MacOS. Of course I recommend to install GNU utilities of all kinds — GNU awk, GNU find, GNU grep, GNU sed, etc…

Comment: No, `-F` and `-E` are both [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). On the other hand, `fgrep` and `egrep` are not (also, their use is deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

Vim is "genetically" related to other text-processing tools, such as `sed` or `grep`. And it also has an embedded sophisticated scripting language, so it is perfectly capable of batch text processing.

But Vim is an interactive text editor, so it feels a little wrong to use it merely as a replacement of `awk` or `grep`. However, if you're going to learn and use it for both editing and scripting, it's elegant and powerful.

To get some taste of Vim, you can solve your problem as follows (typing ':' in normal mode will automatically switch into command mode):

```
:e initial.txt
:g/Lorem/.w! >>processed.txt
```

> I was thinking about vim editor but have no sufficient knowledge on where to search for. Would appreciate any suggestions.

The main problem with Vim is that you have to start from the very beginning, i.e. to learn how to open, edit and save files, and even how to properly exit the application. So you should download and install it and run `vimtutor`. Next, you should get used to Vim's embedded help system (`:h user-manual`) which by far is the best Vim's feature.

If you look for more books and tutorials, you can start from [here](http://vim.begin-site.org). IMHO, Steve Oualline's "Vi IMproved" is still the best for beginners; and Drew Neil's "Practical Vim" is highly recommended for advanced vimmers.